# Съезжают коллайдеры при разных размерах Unity Android

Tags: android, c#, unity3d

Пробовал наносить collider на элемент image canvas, но так как элементы canvas скорее относятся к интерфейсу, да и к тому же когда меняешь различные разрешение экрана, то collider не меняет свой размер по отношению к объекту. Есть ли еще какие-то варианты?

Comment: К примеру, мне бы хотелось бы сделать границы, которые реагируют на коллизию с игроком и его уничтожают, они же являются невидимыми объектами у которых box collider2d присутствуют

Answer (score 0):

Никогда не делайте игру внутри Canvas. Canvas - это интерфейс и ничего более. Дело в том, что при любом изменении внутри него он начнёт целиком отрисовываться заново, а это будет вам серьёзно просаживать производительность.

Используйте обычные спрайты на сцене. У них не будет проблем с коллайдерами) и там можно сделать всё то же самое, что и в кавасе. А скейл реализовать через банальное изменение высоты у камеры.